# Is it possible to remove the alpha channel with jpeglib?

Tags: c, image, image-processing

I need to remove the alpha channel when compressing my RGBA images with JPEG using jpeglib.h.
I can specify the input color space (RGBA) that the source image has (in the jpeg_compress_struct), however this seems to keep the alpha channel in the compressed image.

Does anyone know if it is possible to strip this channel of the alpha channel in the compression? I don't seem to be able to find the correct parameter to set if this is the case.

Comment: JPEG stores an alpha channel? Is that new? This has never been possible!

Comment: Quoting from the jpeglib readme:
"libjpeg-turbo includes extensions that allow JPEG images to be compressed
directly from (and decompressed directly to) buffers that use BGR, BGRX,
RGBX, XBGR, and XRGB pixel ordering. "

Comment: OK, but it doesn’t say that it stores the alpha channel. As far as I know, the JPEG file format doesn’t store an alpha channel. You cannot define transparency in a JPEG file.

Comment: I see what you mean. I think that what it means is that in the decompression phase the alpha channel can be reserved in the memory, but no "real information" is stored there. That information must then be filled in by other means.